# How to propagate .java file change to .class under eclipse, tomcat & stripes

Tags: java, eclipse, class, tomcat, stripes

i'm new to java and i got some problems. i'm developping a web application using the framework stripes on tomcat 6.0.
I'm working with eclipse EE on windows. i successfully managed to get the stripes example application (called Bugzooky) up and running on my tomcat server. I imported the .war file and stripes libs in Eclipse.
[Here is the stripes archive containing the examples and libs](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/stripes/stripes/Stripes%201.5.1/stripes-1.5.1.zip?use_mirror=sunet)

---

But now i'm trying to change the example source files to learn how does it work. but whatever the modification made to the source files "WebContent/WEB-INF/src/*.java", nothing change! even after restarting the server. i noticed that the classes are compiled into .class files in the "ImportedClasses" folder, and tomcat always use these files, they are never updated, and if i removed one of them, the application just don't start. it look like my source files don't exists!

---

I also tried to build my webapp from scratch, but when i tried to use the features used in the example files (like SecurityFilter.java):

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import ...
```

It ends up with plenty of:

```
the import javax.servlet.Filter cannot be resolved
```

I checked the Librairies and it look like i'm using exactly the same as the example.

---

It's probably something i didn't understood about java but i googled 100 times yesterday, and i can't find the solution (i probably didn't search the right place because i don't really understand my problem).

I hope you'll be able to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first problem. With regard to the problem when creating a new project:

> ```
> the import javax.servlet.Filter cannot be resolved
> ```

This means that the web project in Eclipse is not associated with an application server. If this is done correctly, then Eclipse will automatically include the server's libraries (the server is actually a *concrete* implementation of under each the Servlet API) in the project's buildpath.

Did you integrate Tomcat in Eclipse? You can add servers in the *Servers* view at the right bottom box. Did you associate the web project with the particular Tomcat instance? You need to select the server in the *Targeted Runtimes* section of the project's *Properties*. This is by the way normally to be done during creating the *Dynamic Web Project*.

Comment: Ok, my tomcat was linked right but i didn't choosed the Targeted Runtime. It works fine! Thanks a lot, you saved my time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile all the changed `.java` files, rebuild the `.war` file and redeploy it to Tomcat. This is most easily done with an Ant build script. Look for a file called `build.xml`. If it is there install [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) if you don't already have it installed and you can then just execute the `ant` command in the directory with the `build.xml` file and then copy the resulting `.war` file over the existing one in Tomcat. This is all basic Java App server work flow stuff.

Comment: That sounds good, but i think i'll need this only for the deployement, i don't need to create a war each time i made a change to a file (during developpement) Eclipse seams to update tomcat fine. Thank you for your answer, it help me progress =)